# In Excel, populate array based on table with value (and coordinates for desired array cell). All array cells are populated (default to be zero)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am reasonably good with Excel but a near novice at VBA.  I have a three column table.  Column A & B have coordinates for an array, with column C having the value to be placed as defined by the coordinates.  Not all cells of the array are listed, with the empty cells to have a default 'zero'.  Need to populate the array with the values.  Seems simple, but I am lost!

Comment: What do you mean by "array"? A list of the numbers in a cell? Something that is inserted into a formula? A graph?

Comment: specifically, a 20 x 20 table (2-dimensional array).  The top left cell would have coordinates (1,1) and the bottom right hand cell would have coordinates (20,20).  -- and yes, I know VBA usually starts numbering with (0,0) and that is easily solved.  Thanks.

Comment: Just use an [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) and then spit it back out to `cells(x,y)`

Comment: sorry, does that work?  column A and B are the x, y coordinates.  Column C contains the value for the Cell(x,y).  I figured some sort of nested loops in VBA would be required.  And thanks for your interest and help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with an array, you could do something like this (assume the table starts at E5)

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim item As String

For Each c In Range("A1:A3")
    x = c.Value
    y = c.Offset(, 1).Value
    item = c.Offset(, 2).Value
    Cells(4 + x, 4 + y) = item
Next

End Sub
```

To find the empty cells and put in the zeroes, you could do something like -

```
Dim d As Range
For Each d In Range("E5:G7")
    If IsEmpty(d) Then
    d = 0
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works, although I might need to add a loop (??).  An elegant solution !

Comment: In VBA `for each ... next` doesn't need `loop`. `Do` needs `loop` though.

Comment: @DennisH if this solved your question, go ahead and click the green checkmark to the left to mark the question as solved